# tokenInstance.balanceOf is not a function

Tags: truffle

It happen when use truffle test,

[image]

and here my DappTokenSale file:

```
var DappToken = artifacts.require('./DappToken.sol');
var DappTokenSale = artifacts.require('./DappTokenSale.sol');

contract('DappTokenSale', function(accounts) {
    var tokenInstance;
    var tokenSaleInstance;
    var admin = accounts[0];
    var buyer = accounts[1]; 
    var tokenPrice = 1000000000000000;
    var tokensAvailable = 750000;
    var numberOfTokens;

    it('Initializes the contract with the correct values', function() {
        return DappTokenSale.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            tokenSaleInstance = instance;
            return tokenSaleInstance.address
        }).then(function(address) {
            assert.notEqual(address, 0x0, "has contract address");
            return tokenSaleInstance.tokenContract();
        }).then(function(address) {
            assert.notEqual(address, 0x0, "has token contract address");
            return tokenSaleInstance.tokenPrice();
        }).then(function(price) {
            assert.equal(price, tokenPrice, 'token price is correct');
        });
    });

    it('facilitates token buying', function(){
        return DappToken.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            tokenInstance = instance;
            return DappTokenSale.deployed();
        }).then(function(instance){
            tokenSaleInstance = instance;
            return tokenInstance.transfer(tokenSaleInstance.address, tokensAvailable, {from: admin})
        }).then(function(receipt){
            numberOfTokens = 10;
            return tokenSaleInstance.buyTokens(numberOfTokens, { from: buyer, value: numberOfTokens*tokenPrice})
        }).then(function(receipt) {
            assert.equal(receipt.logs.length, 1, 'triggers one event');
            assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].event, 'Sell', 'should be the "Sell" event');
            assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._buyer, buyer, 'logs the account that purchased the tokens');
            assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._amount, numberOfTokens, 'logs the number of tokens purchased');
            return tokenSaleInstance.tokensSold();
        }).then(function(amount){
            assert.equal(amount.toNumber(), numberOfTokens, 'increments the number of tokens sold');
            return tokenInstance.balanceOf(buyer);
        }).then(function(balance) {
            assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), numberOfTokens);
            return tokenInstance.balanceOf(tokenSaleInstance.address);
        }).then(function(balance){
            assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), tokensAvailable - numberOfTokens);
            return tokenSaleInstance.buyTokens(numberOfTokens, { from: buyer, value: 1});
        }).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error) {
            assert(error.message.indexOf('revert') >= 0, 'msg.value must equal number of tokens in wei')
            return tokenSaleInstance.buyTokens(800000, {from: buyer, value: numberOfTokens*tokenPrice})
        }).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error) {
            assert(error.message.indexOf('revert') >= 0, 'cannot purchased more than available token');
        });
    });

    it('end token sale', function() {
        return DappTokenSale.deployed().then(function(instance){
            tokenInstance = instance;
            return DappTokenSale.deployed();
        }).then(function(instance){
            tokenSaleInstance = instance;
            return tokenSaleInstance.endSale({from:buyer });
        }).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error){
            assert(error.message.indexOf('revert' >= 0, 'must be admin to end sale'));
            return tokenSaleInstance.endSale({from: admin});
        }).then(function(receipt){
            return tokenInstance.balanceOf(admin);
        }).then(function(balance){
            assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), 999990, 'return all unsold dapp tokens to admin')
            return tokenSaleInstance.tokenPrice();
        }).then(function(price) {
            assert.equal(price.toNumber(), 0,'token price was reset')
        });
    });
    });
```

Comment: Why someone down vote my question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems tokenInstance is improperly initialized in 'end token sale'.

```
it('end token sale', function() {
    //     Here it should be DappToken and not DappTokenSale
    //     like in your unit test
    //     vvvvvvvvv
    return DappToken.deployed().then(function(instance){
        tokenInstance = instance;
        return DappTokenSale.deployed();
    }).then(function(instance){
        tokenSaleInstance = instance;
        return tokenSaleInstance.endSale({from:buyer });
```

Comment: Yes!, you're right,thanks you, what a silly mistake